# How can I embed selenium browser inside of pyqy window

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pywin32

I want to embed selenium inside of pyqt5 application. I've tried to use win32gui to findwindow and move into the qt window. HOWEVER, it never works naturally and keyboard press does not work inside of qt.
I need to embed selenium or just show selenium inside of qt which needs to work well. (I cant use webview)

HOW CAN I?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.